# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<AppColors>' Mock and Shared Preferences tests

Tags: flutter, mockito, sharedpreferences

I am learning provider and I wanna to learn how to test loading data from SharedPreferences and I don't know what is wrong in the code it's right. I look into stackoverflow, tried AI, but it's answering always the same thing.

How can I test calling from SharedPreferences and use when?

My app it’s a generator of colors palette, I have a provider class that load colors and update, repository that save colors in shared preferences.

Error:

```
    type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<AppColors>'
    test/theme_provider_test.dart 7:7    MockThemeRepository.loadThemeColors
    test/theme_provider_test.dart 18:24  main
```

My test:

```dart
    class MockThemeRepository extends Mock implements ThemeRepository {}
        
            void main() {
             WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        
             final themeRepository = MockThemeRepository();
        
             when(themeRepository.loadThemeColors()).thenAnswer((_) async => AppColors(
                primary: Colors.blue,
                accent: Colors.orange,
                background: Colors.white,
                backgroundDark: Colors.grey,
                error: Colors.red,
              ));
        
            test('Test if the theme colors are loaded from SharedPreferences', () async {
             final loadedColors = await themeRepository.loadThemeColors();
        
             expect(loadedColors.primary, equals(Colors.blue));
             expect(loadedColors.accent, equals(Colors.orange));
             expect(loadedColors.background, equals(Colors.white));
             expect(loadedColors.backgroundDark, equals(Colors.grey));
             expect(loadedColors.error, equals(Colors.red));
            });
```

Repository

```dart
    class ThemeRepository {
            static const String themeColorsKey = 'themeColors';
            final _logger = Logger();
            
            Future<AppColors> loadThemeColors() async {
             try {
              final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              final encodedData = prefs.getString(themeColorsKey);
              if (encodedData != null) {
                final colorsData = json.decode(encodedData);
                return AppColors.fromJson(colorsData);
               }
              } catch (error, stackTrace) {
              _logger.e('Falha ao carregar as cores do tema', error, stackTrace);
             }
             // Retorna cores padrão em caso de falha ou ausência de cores salvas
             return AppColors.defaultColors();
             }
            }
```

Provider

```dart
      ThemeProvider(
        this.themeData,
        this.currentThemeColors,
      );
    
      Future<void> loadThemeColors() async {
        try {
          final appColors = await repository.loadThemeColors();
    
          updateThemeFromColors(appColors);
        } catch (error, stackTrace) {
          _logger.e('Falha ao carregar as cores do tema', error, stackTrace);
        }
      }

    void updateThemeFromColors(AppColors colors) {
        final newTheme = themeData.copyWith(
          colorScheme: themeData.colorScheme.copyWith(
            primary: colors.primary,
            secondary: colors.accent,
            background: colors.background,
            error: colors.error,
          ),
          primaryColor: colors.primary,
          appBarTheme: themeData.appBarTheme.copyWith(
            backgroundColor: colors.backgroundDark,
          ),
          floatingActionButtonTheme: themeData.floatingActionButtonTheme.copyWith(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                return colors.accent;
              }
              return colors.accent;
            }),
          ),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: colors.background,
        );
    themeData = newTheme;
    currentThemeColors = colors;
    repository.saveThemeColors(colors);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: But JUnit it`s for Java,right?

Comment: Oops, at first glance this looked like Java :blush: